# How to create pandas dataframe from array([[[135, 2270.24]]], dtype=object)

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe

I am embarassed with this. I would like to transform this array to pandas dataframe with one column let's say called "feature" and one value: [135, 2270.24]:
array([[[135, 2270.24]]], dtype=object)

I tried this but returns ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
`df = pd.DataFrame(C, columns = ['feature'])` with C the array.

Comment: You want the cell value to be a list or an array? I highly recommend you re-think that organization; `pandas` is meant to work with flat data where each cell is a simple object, `str`, `int`, `float`..., not a container that holds many items.

Comment: @k_bm Please post the input in Python and give an expected output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I follow exactly what you're asking for. But if my interpretation is correct you're looking for something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup
val = np.array([[[135, 2270.24]]])

# logic
data = [{'feature': val[0][0]}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output `df`:

```
    feature
0   [135.0, 2270.24]
```